# Making Qt buttons connected to each other

Tags: button, qt4

I'd like to accomplish this effect, with Qt4 libraries: a button group that attaches every button that is next to it. In Gtk3 I simply apply the "linked" class to the container widget. How can this be done in Qt4?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Qt, to create a group of linked buttons, you can use a [`QButtonGroup`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html) with checkable buttons inside it.

Note that this class is not a visual container, you need to lay out your buttons (or whatever else) yourself using normal layout techniques.
(An alternative is the [`QGroupBox`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgroupbox.html), which does have a visual appearance.)

It's relatively straightforward to use a group box and [style sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) to achieve this effect.

```
#include <QtGui>

// For Qt 5:
// #include <QtWidgets>

static QString strip_normal(
"QPushButton {"
"   margin: 0; padding: 10px; border: 0px;"
"   background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
"                              stop: 0 #f6f7fa, stop: 1 #aaabae);"
"}");
static QString strip_checked(
"QPushButton:checked {"
"   background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,"
"                              stop: 0 #aaabae, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);"
"}");
static QString strip_first(
"QPushButton{"
"   border-top-left-radius: 6px;"
"   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;"
"}");
static QString strip_last(
"QPushButton{"
"   border-top-right-radius: 6px;"
"   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;"
"}");

static QString widget_back(
"QWidget {"
"   background: black;"
"}");
```

<sub>Gradients taken from the [QPushButton styling examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton), slight tweak.</sub>

```
class W: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        W(QWidget *parent = 0)
            : QWidget(parent)
        {
            /* style sheet applies to this widget and its children */
            setStyleSheet(widget_back+strip_normal+strip_checked);

            /* First and last widget need special borders */
            QPushButton *one = createButton("one",   true,  strip_first);
            QPushButton *two = createButton("two",   false);
            QPushButton *thr = createButton("three", false, strip_last);

            /* Button group for button selection handling */
            QButtonGroup *bg = new QButtonGroup;
            bg->addButton(one);
            bg->addButton(two);
            bg->addButton(thr);

            /* Layout with no spacing */
            QHBoxLayout *hl = new QHBoxLayout;
            hl->addWidget(one);
            hl->addWidget(two);
            hl->addWidget(thr);
            hl->setSpacing(0);

            setLayout(hl);
        }

        QPushButton *createButton(QString const& name,
                                  bool checked,
                                  QString const& sheet = QString())
        {
            QPushButton *pb = new QPushButton(name);
            pb->setCheckable(true);
            pb->setChecked(checked);
            if (!sheet.isEmpty())
                pb->setStyleSheet(sheet);
            return pb;
        }
};
```

This will look like the screen shots below (depending on your OS and whatever Qt customization you might have):

- Linux, no styling whatsoever:

  [image]
- Stylesheet as in the code above:

  [image]

Other alternative that may help you, depending on what semantics that "control" has for you: the [`QTabBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html) which is the top widget in a tabbed windows (the tab selector).

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is, in addiction to the behaviour, the style: the buttons are physically connected to each other :)